# How to query geodata from DBpedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to fetch geodata from DBpedia for a specific resource, e.g., a city, a building, or something else.  Two examples are:

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eiffel_Tower
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Paris

I tried this query, but I cant get it working:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
SELECT ?subject ?label ?lat ?long WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eiffel_Tower>
  ?subject geo:lat ?lat .
  ?subject geo:long ?long .
  ?subject rdfs:label ?label .
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ?subject ?label ?lat ?long WHERE {  
?subject owl:sameAs <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eiffel_Tower> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eiffel_Tower> geo:lat ?lat.
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eiffel_Tower> geo:long ?long.
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eiffel_Tower> rdfs:label ?label . }
```

You can always try your query on http://dbpedia.org/isparql/ or http://dbpedia.org/snorql/

Comment: Thank you, don't have sufficient reputation to vote your answer up, but this is exactly what I needed!